# Strange visual artifacts in sublime text 2 on macosx

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, visual-artifacts

Sublime Text started displaying strange atrifacts

[image: strange artifacts]

It was opened for at least couple days and everything was fine. It was idle for about an hour after I wrote some code.

I've already restarted both Sublime Text and iMac. Also I tried to change themes and color schemes. All the same.

The code editor works fine, but status bar and browser panel gone crazy.

[image]

Comment: Reinstall and see if that corrects the issue.  I've been using ST2 for a year on 3 Macs and I've never seen that problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've removed ST2 and installed ST3. All works for now.